# почему цикл ищет не все записи?

Tags: excel, vba

Дано: VBA-процедура, которая ищет и выводит все значения из таблицы entity_attributes_xref, соответствующие условию: entityID=25 и value_txt содержит «неверное значение атрибута»

```
Private Sub subTest1() Dim rs1 As Recordset, s1 As String
    s1 = "SELECT id_entity_attributes, entityID FROM entity_attributes_xref WHERE value_txt Like '*неверное значение атрибута*'"
    Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(s1, dbOpenSnapshot)
        Do While rs1.EOF = False
            If rs1.Fields("entityID") = 25 Then
                Debug.Print rs1.Fields("id_entit`введите сюда код`y_attributes")
            End If
        Loop
    rs1.Close: Set rs1 = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: А, почему нельзя проверку `entityID=25` перенести в сам ЫЙД запрос?

Comment: Так условие поставлено(
2-й день сижу уже с этим

Comment: В SQL запросе, у Вас нет этого условия. Вы получаете все записи и потом в VBA в цикле отбираете нужные.

Comment: Но почему-то через цикл проходят не все записи.
Это может быть из-за того что мы не берем value в цикле?

Comment: @Streletz Или правильно в цикле условие?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно значение поля а не само поле. Попробуйте

```
    If rs1.Fields("entityID").value
```

Answer (score 0):

1. у Streletz идея уже по оптимизации программы, естественно проще сразу отобрать нужные данные на SQL стороне
2. `rs1.Fields("entityID").value` - не принципиально, и так бы работал, если кто-нибудь запустил с тестовыми данными, такое довольно редко нужно уточнять в VBA-окружении.
3. правильный ответ - синтаксис цикла не дописан, нет команды перехода на следующую запись (.MoveNext), без него зацикливается бесконечно на первой записи и из Loop не выйдет! Это - одно из самых критичных условий, это написано в любом хелпе по VBA о Recordset (OpenRecordset) как во встроенной справке по F1 на первых страницах из кода, так и в интернете

Comment: Не следует негативно отзываться о других участниках. Старайтесь писать по делу, не переходя на личности.

Comment: никто не переходил на личности - я говорил о стажерах в целом, где переход на личность топикстартера?

Comment: во-вторых то, что они публикуют детали приватной переписки это нормально?

Comment: в-третьих вот вырезанный текст: позор стажерам, это тестовое задание при устройстве на работу, побежали спрашивать stackoverflow... всё готовое подавай сразу не включая мозг. В вакансии-то были указаны требования базовых навыков работы с БД в VBA!